# How can I solve the Type inference failed warnining in Tensorflow 2.9?

Tags: python, tensorflow, types

I'm running a grid search optimization using `LSTM` and `MultiHeadAttention` layers, and many models are being created and trained. The following warning appears as soon as I call the first `model.fit()`:

```
2023-06-13 13:05:54.007627: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/forward_type_inference.cc:231] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_LEGACY_VARIANT
    }
  }
}
 is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_INT8
    }
  }
}

  while inferring type of node 'cond_40/output/_25'
```

This warning provokes the kernel to go down (I'm using Spyder, and a red box with this warning appears in the console, so I have to restart it), so I can't have more information about the exception occurred nor the specific model that caused the problem.

I'm using garbage collector at the end of each epoch and clearing the keras session at the end of each training, so I suppose it is not a OOM exception:

```py
# Define Garbage collector
class ClearMemory(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        gc.collect()

# (...)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

I have referred to this issue https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16978, but the suggestion"is just a warning, you can safely ignore it." is not working for me. Help please.